# magento product option boxes style

Tags: magento, checkbox, layout, product

Hi I am novice at magento I just can do simple task and edit some css but now I need to redesign product page layout. What I cant do is change product options (like shoes size, or clothes S,M,XL etc..).
Now it has classic dropdown manu layout what i want is little boxes with options, like checkboxes.
See exemple here [example of product](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-Men-s-running-shoes-2013-flat-heels-Casual-shoes-Men-s-fashion-sport-shoes/818399730.html)

i dont know if there is some plugin for that or you need to see some source code to help me, if so write a comment i try paste neccesary code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add custom option for product,,,,you can see in manage product option in last tab custom option...

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: just go to catalog>manage product and got o your product and open and you can see in last tab custom option just click on that and now you can here you can add your product custom like dropdown,textfield etc...

Answer (score 0):

The options for configurable products are created here:

> ../template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Just edit the *.phtml to your needs. In default it is a simple select box.